# Why the electric field inside a conductor is zero?

Tags: electrostatics, electric-fields, conductors

In electromagnetism books, such as Griffiths or the like, when they talk about the properties of conductors in case of electrostatics they say that the electric field inside a conductor is zero.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/22773/2451

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In an ideal conductor electrons are free to move. So when you apply an electric field to the conductor the electrons will feel a force $F=qE$ and start to move. This causes a charge separation which produces an electric field by itself. The net electric field is therefore a superposition of the external field and the field due to the charge separation. The electrons will continue to move until the net electric field inside the conductor is zero.

Note1: From this physical picture you can also infer that the charges will always accumulate on the surface of the conductor.

Note2: If you are wondering how the electrons know how to rearrange so that the net electric field is zero, just assume that the net electric field is non-zero. This causes a force $F=qE$ and the charge will separate along the electric field lines. This creates an electric field which is opposite to the external field that created the charge separation.

Answer (score 1):

Remarkably, the question, in its current form, is word for word the opening sentence of [this question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/22773/in-electrostatics-why-the-electric-field-inside-a-conductor-is-zero)

> In electromagnetism books, such as Griffiths or the like, when they
>   talk about the properties of conductors in case of electrostatics they
>   say that the electric field inside a conductor is zero.

and is thus a duplicate.

Regardless, the answer is actually more a simple matter of logic rather than physics.

(1) By definition, charge is *free* to move inside a conductor.

(2) By definition, charge is *not* moving for the electro *static* case.

(3) Free charge is accelerated by an electric field.

Thus, it follows that, in the electrostatic case, there is no electric field inside a conductor since, if there were, it would *not* be the electrostatic case as there would be acceleration of charge.

Answer (score 0):

As long as electric field is not zero, charge carriers (e.g., electrons) keep moving inside a conductor, so to say, steady state has not been reached. And in a steady state no charge carriers are moving and electric field must be zero.