# electric field inside a conducting body

Tags: electrostatics, electric-fields

From Gauss' Law, we know that the electric field inside a solid conducting sphere varies linearly with the distance from the centre. But we also know that electric field inside a conductor is zero.

How is this possible? Please explain me!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [In electrostatics, why the electric field inside a conductor is zero?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/22773/in-electrostatics-why-the-electric-field-inside-a-conductor-is-zero)

Comment: Sure, it varies linearly. If $x$ is the distance from the center, and $f$ is the electric field, then $f = kx$, where $k = 0$.

Answer (score 2):

The field inside a conducting sphere is zero, not linear in $r$. The field of a uniformly charged sphere goes linearly with $r$.

Comment: can you derive the expression for electric field due to a uniformly charged sphere using only coulomb's law not using gauss' law ???

Comment: @Subhadipb Pal: One question at a time. Don't ask anyone to do homework type questions, please.

Comment: Please accept Kyson's answer if you think it answered your question. Saying "thank you very much" is not the way to go in this site.

Answer (score 0):

from Gauss' Law  electric field inside a solid insulating sphere varies linearly not in conducting sphere. inside a conducting sphere it will be zero.