# Electric field inside a charged conductor

Tags: electric-fields

Why is electric field inside a charged  conductor always zero? In an uncharged conductor if an electric field is applied then the charges reconfigure themselves as to have no net electric field. In a case of a charged conductor when a net electric field always zero even when there is no electric field applied. Can someone explain both the cases. When there is no electric field applied and when there is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you need to do is think about the fact that at any place inside a conductor the local charge can move around.

So if there is an electric field at any given place, then the charge there *will* move around. It will be accelerated in the direction of the electric field.

Now you *can* have an electric field inside a conductor in a dynamic situation. This is what happens inside an antenna when it is absorbing or emitting radio waves, for example. But it is the **static** case where the electric field has to be zero. It must be zero because if it were not zero then the charge would be accelerating so the situation would not be static!

Note the logic here. So far I have not given a demonstration of the physical cause of why the electric field is zero (I will come to that in a moment). It is a piece of detective work. The argument is saying "in view of the fact that the charge here is not accelerating, the electric field must be zero." The detective has determined that since the body is dead, it has been killed, but he does not yet know how or why.

So now let's come to the how and why. What happens is that the charges inside the conductor move, and move again, and keeping moving, moving, and thus build up in one place or another, and as they do so they are themselves producing electric fields. And the lovely thing is, as soon as some charge accumulates in one place, it will produce a field such as to discourage other charge from going there (because like charges repel). Thus you have the possibility that eventually (and in practice pretty quickly) the charge can find a configuration so that it just cancels, inside the conductor at least, whatever fields would otherwise be there, by itself providing an equal and opposite field. As soon as the charge manages to find that configuration, it will stay there so the whole situation is stable.

Comment: Can you explain what happens if it gets charged

Comment: @ Andrew Steane . I understand that.., but I think your explanation does not neglect the possibility of a forever dynamic situation. So that there can be cases where the electric field will never be zero. How can we neglect that possibility? Without relying on experiments?

Comment: @BlackSusanoo Nothing in the answer requires it to be uncharged. It could be charged or uncharged. It doesn't matter.

Comment: @AdityaSharma You don't get permanent oscillation owing to small amounts of resistance so that there is dissipation. No conductor is a perfect conductor. With superconductivity you can get permanent current but not permanent oscillation because in that case some energy will be radiated away.

Comment: This doesn't actually tells us that the electric field must vanish inside, I think. We can argue that free electrons will all repel each other and thus end up on the surface, but then a priori the electric field could be doing any sort of thing in the interior where it has no free charges to act on.

Comment: @mpc That's a good point but the free electrons do not all end up on the surface. e.g. in a mole of copper there are about  $6\times 10^{23}$ free electrons, with total charge 96000 C. A mole of copper has a volume approx 7 cm$^3$ so a surface area approx 20 cm$^2$ (in a cube or sphere). If all the free charge were at the surface then the surface charge density would be $5 \times 10^7$C/m$^3$ so the electric field outside would be $5 \times 10^{11}$ V/m. But break down occurs at fields of order $10^6$ V/m. I deduce that it is not possible to bring all the free charge to the surface.

Comment: P.S. also the electrons are attracted to the positively-charge atomic nuclei. This largely cancels out the repulsive forces between them. After averaging over a few atoms' worth of distance, the attractive and repulsive forces on any given electron are balancing out.

Comment: Quite right. For lack of sleep I conflated [free electrons go to the surface] and [any net charge congregates on the surface].